# Mysql ORDER BY with dot(.)

Tags: mysql

I saw this code snippet in an tutorial. but i don't know what's the purpose of .()dot between a and b. Please, can someone explain that.

```
ORDER BY `a`.`b` DESC LIMIT 1
```

The code is as follow

```
SELECT * 
FROM pop_outlog 
ORDER BY pop_outlog.time_sent DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

What's the purpose of doing so rather than using only column name?

Comment: It should be the table name (a) and the column name (b)

Comment: a is table name , b is column name check the reference  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: It separates identifiers. The name (or full name) can consists of `db_name.table_name.field_name`.

Comment: Please can some one explain,why downvoted? there can be someone who don't think very simple stuff. That's why i asked from who knows better that me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basic question.

```
ORDER BY `table_name`.`column_name` DESC LIMIT 1
```

it can be used any where if column is allowed. like this

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col2
ORDER BY t1.col1
GROUPY BY t2.col2
```

Comment: but in this senarion SELECT *
  FROM `pop_outlog`
  ORDER BY `pop_outlog`.`time_sent` DESC LIMIT 1; why it's used ?

Comment: @user3001352 hello, you can omit `pop_outlog` in ORDER BY. why? `pop_outlog.time_sent` and `time_sent` is same. the author of query just inserted (i guess)